# Implement a Proxy Pattern for a Tastypie Resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a `FooResource` that is related to a `BarResource` through a `toOneField` as my `FooModel` has a FK to `BarModel`. What I'm really interested in is `BlahModel` represented through the `BlahResource`. So I can logically get to a `BlahModel` from a `BarModel`, how should I handle this with Tastypie, so that when there's a

```
bar = fields.ToOneField(BarResource, 'bar', full=True)
```

in the `FooResource`, I actually get the data from a `BlahModel` instead of the `BarModel`?

I know I can't use a `ToOneField` in `BarResource` to `BlahResource` as there is no corresponding FK in the model. I would prefer not to end up in a complicated `dehydrate` hack as well. What is the easiest way to implement a Proxy Pattern in a Tastypie ModelResource?